# Loading wordpress stuff on laravel site

Tags: php

I not sure why i failed to load the wordpress site on the laravel site. the following code, i tested on plain php without any framework - it work! but if i call from the file within laravel framework - it failed!!

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);     
require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php'); 
wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container' => false,
    'menu_class' => 'menu',
    'menu_id' => '',
    'fallback_cb' => false
));
```

i not sure what's the problem and the following is the trace catch from the error:

> **array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given**

```
function mo_get_theme_option($option_id, $default = null, $single = true) {
    global $mo_theme;
    global $options_cache;

    if (array_key_exists($option_id, $options_cache))
        return $options_cache[$option_id];
```

Comment: Where does `$options_cache` get populated? What does `var_dump( $options_cache );` reveal? Clearly this is where your problem lies (if the last snippet is related). | Also, I don't see how this is related to WP.

Comment: @JohannesPille, i'm trying to get the nav menu of wordpress into the laravel website. and i downloaded entire live version of wordpress to my local folder to test it out. the array_key_exist is from the template file i think..

Comment: You've defined `WP_USE_THEMES` to false, but are using theme related code.

Comment: @s_ha_dum, but i use only the function wp_nav_menu. tried get_header as well. also failed

Comment: Look at that function call-- `'theme_location' => 'primary',`. Notice that part about the theme? And the other function: `mo_get_theme_option`. Also notice the part about the theme? Try without `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);` just for fun.

Comment: @s_ha_dum, still the same.. lol, no matter i remove the use theme or remove the theme location..

Comment: Which theme are you using? Please link to it (note if it's commercial without easy access to source that pushes it out of scope here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to do that just to output a WP menu on a Lavarel site?

In this case you are loading all WordPress environment (themes, plugins, options...) just for a menu. This not seems to me a great thing.

Probably, the most elegant approach for this, should be in Laravel create the eloquent models for the involved WP tables, a Controller a View to to output the menu.
All using Laravel code, in this way you don't need to load WP.. Of course you can copy the code from WP core and *translate* in Laravel...

Laravel is great to semplificate thing, however I understand that this can appear *a lot of work* compared to just an include...

For this reason, and to not write an off-topic answer, **I'll suggest you another approach**.

**In the WordPress root folder, create a subfolder named, e.g. `'tmp'`**.

This folder is a sort of exchange folder from WP to Lavarel. Be sure WordPress can write files in this folder.

After that, in the `functions.php` of the active theme in WordPress put something like:

```
add_action('load-nav-menus.php', 'go_cache_menu');

function go_cache_menu() {
  add_action('shutdown', 'cache_menu');
}

function cache_menu() {
    $filename = trailingslashit(ABSPATH) . '/tmp/primary-menu.inc';
    $content = wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location' => 'primary',
      'container' => false,
      'menu_class' => 'menu',
      'menu_id' => '',
      'fallback_cb' => false,
      'echo'  => false
    )); 
    file_put_contents ( $filename , $content );
}
```

This code, when you visit the nav menu page, create a file in the `tmp` folder,  named `primary-menu.inc` that contain your menu. When you update the menu, that file is updated.

After that, in Laravel you can retrieve the content of this file, like so:

```
$path = './wordpress/tmp/primary-menu.inc';
$menu_content = @file_get_contents($path) ? : '';
```

And then pass the `$menu_content` to Lavarel views to display it... The performance of your Lavarel site will improve a lot without loading WordPress! (and if you use a Blade template the content of your menu will be also auto-cached...)

Comment: Exactly!! I immediately use the ob to catch the return and then dump them into a variable, write the content to file (blade.php) immediately then move to the laravel view folder. yea.. it's damn a lot of work to reverse the wordpress into laravel :/ hope someone with strong skill on both framework work it out and i will be one of contributor :P Thx

Comment: when I remove the menu, primary-menu.inc is not updated.

Comment: @lyhong this is a proof of concept code to betterexplain the answer. Is not intended to be some code you copy and paste on production.